# Why won't this search by OU?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to validate a user's login credentials based on their organizational unit in Active Directory. How can I do this?

This is my attempt so far, but I can't get it to specify by OU.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
"domain", "OU=LRF,OU=HR,OU=Users, DC=domain, DC=local"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
    if (isValid == true)
    {
        new Form1().Show();
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Access Denied");
}
```

Comment: Do you really need three different units there: `OU=LRF,OU=HR,OU=Users`? Also, explain clearly what did you expect to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: I expect the user's username and password to be validated based on their Organizational Unit. So if a user is an HR user, they shouldn't get past the login form that takes them to the IT form.

Comment: I just assumed that's how I got the whole OU path. I'm not really sure how to do it

Comment: It works perfectly for checking the entire active directory. But I want to check based on OU within the directory

Comment: I suspect that these units are nested into each other. What if you try to remove `OU=Users` from query string? Or just leave HR: `OU=HR, DC=domain, DC=local`

Comment: That I haven't tried. I will tomorrow morning and let you know if it works